# Simple Savon SOAP request not working

Tags: ruby, savon

I have the following WSDL, generated from soapUI. When I test the
request from soapUI, it works fine but throws exception from savon.
I am using savon 0.9.2 on Linux.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/
envelope/" xmlns:mes="http://www.domain.com/sub/05/00/Messages">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mes:loginRequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mes:Username>admin</mes:Username>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mes:Password>pass</mes:Password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mes:ImpersonationUsername></mes:ImpersonationUsername>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mes:ApplicationName></mes:ApplicationName>
      </mes:loginRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The script, which causes Errors:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'savon'
require 'pp'

client = Savon::Client.new "http://domain/Service.asmx?WSDL"

response = client.request(:mes, "login") do
  soap.body = {
"mes:Username" => "test",
"mes:Password" => "test",
"mes:ImpersonationUsername"=>"Test",
"mes:ApplicationName"=>"test"
}
end
pp response.to_hash
```

The Output:

```
D, [2011-05-10T16:06:14.316827 #11254] DEBUG -- : <?xml version="1.0"
encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://
schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/
XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/
XMLSchema"><soap:Body><LoginResult xmlns="http://www.domain.com/sub/
05/00/
Messages"><ErrorDetails><Items><SfExceptionItem><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException</
ExceptionType><AssemblyName>mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b73a5c561934e089</
AssemblyName><Message>Object reference not set to an instance of an
object.</Message></SfExceptionItem></Items><FaultCode>UnknownError</
FaultCode><Message>Object reference not set to an instance of an
object.</Message></ErrorDetails></LoginResult></soap:Body></
soap:Envelope>
{:login_result=>
  {:error_details=>
    {:items=>
      {:sf_exception_item=>
        {:message=>"Object reference not set to an instance of an
object.",
         :exception_type=>"System.NullReferenceException",
         :assembly_name=>
          "mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b73a5c561934e089"}},
     :message=>"Object reference not set to an instance of an
object.",
     :fault_code=>"UnknownError"},
   :xmlns=>
    "http://www.domain.com/sub/05/00/Messages"}}
```

The output from SoapUI is the following:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <LoginResult xmlns="http://domain/sub/05/00/Messages">
         <UserTicket>95bfaa81149f4c118c8724b837235cd5</UserTicket>
      </LoginResult>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: contact me via github (https://github.com/rubiii) and i'll have a look at this tomorrow!

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler to see how the requests differ between SoapUI and Savon?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set the namespace in your savon request: `client.namespaces["xmlns:mes"] = "http://www.domain.com/sub/05/00/Messages"`

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't seem to be working. `client = Savon::Client.new do 
 wsdl.endpoint = "http://domain/sub/Service.asmx"
 wsdl.namespace = "http://www.domain.com/sub/05/00"
end`

Answer (score 0):

the request you send creates the following soap message

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xmlns:mes="urn:namespace.com"
                  xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <mes:login>
    <mes:Username>test</mes:Username>
    <mes:Password>test</mes:Password>
    <mes:ImpersonationUsername>Test</mes:ImpersonationUsername>
    <mes:ApplicationName>test</mes:ApplicationName>
    </mes:login>
  </env:Body>
```

I guess that's not what your intention is?
please insert the following lines into your code after the .new

```
Savon.configure do |c|
  c.log = true
end
```

that shows the outgoing message.

Comment: I can see the outgoing messages from STDOUT, but my problem is that the response from savon script is not the same as the response from soapUI. It should return `<UserTicket>95bfaa81149f4c118c8724b837235cd5</UserTicket>`